# Target page refresh either by javascript or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am trying to figure out how can I refresh a target page when visited either by a hyperlink or the back button, or even a button. Any ideas ? I have tried almost any solution I could find online and still can make the target page refresh after visited.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: What do you mean by "refresh?" What are you expecting to see?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can refresh the page using JavaScript with this code:

```
location.reload();
```

But if you don't put a condition on it, it'll refresh forever, right?

You'll need to describe your issue in more detail.

Comment: this also presumes he controls the target page and can add this data to it.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to reload page when page full loaded use this JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    location.reload();
});
```

if you want timer when page loaded and then reload it use:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // reload after 5 second
  setTimeout(function() {
     location.reload();
  }, 5000);
});
```

if you want reload only first time use this:

```
function setCookie(cookieName,cookieValue,nDays) {
 var today = new Date();
 var expire = new Date();
 if (nDays==null || nDays==0) nDays=1;
 expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*nDays);
 document.cookie = cookieName+"="+escape(cookieValue)
                 + ";expires="+expire.toGMTString();
}

function getCookie(cookieName) {
 var theCookie=" "+document.cookie;
 var ind=theCookie.indexOf(" "+cookieName+"=");
 if (ind==-1) ind=theCookie.indexOf(";"+cookieName+"=");
 if (ind==-1 || cookieName=="") return "";
 var ind1=theCookie.indexOf(";",ind+1);
 if (ind1==-1) ind1=theCookie.length; 
 return unescape(theCookie.substring(ind+cookieName.length+2,ind1));
}
```

So, you would tie it together like this:

```
$(function() {

     var skipModal = getCookie('skipModal');
     if (!skipModal) { // check and see if a cookie exists indicating we should skip the modal
         // show your modal here


         setCookie('skipModal', 'true', 365*5); // set a cookie indicating we should skip the modal
     }
});
```

show this link:

[Fire jquery script on first page load, and then never again for that user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617555/fire-jquery-script-on-first-page-load-and-then-never-again-for-that-user)