# Show bootstrap modal on rendering another template

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I wrote bootstrap modal and I put it in separate template. Open it base on click button I can, but now I try to show it when another template is rendered. Important, I want to invoke modal only once. For example when page is reflesh and template is rendered second time I don't want to show modal second time.  It is simple message after user log in. How should I bite the problem? Thanks for any help.

Below it is my work:

(html)

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade welcome-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="gridSystemModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header text-center text-uppercase">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="gridSystemModalLabel">Welcome!</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body text-center">
                <div>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
                </div>
                <div>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-left">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Not Now</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">Edit Profile</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(css)

```
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .welcome-modal .modal-dialog {
            width: 400px;
        }
    }
    .welcome-modal .modal-header {
        border-bottom-width: 0;
        padding: 20px 35px 0 35px;
    }
    .welcome-modal .modal-body {
        border-top-width: 0;
        padding: 20px 35px 0 35px;
    }
    .welcome-modal .modal-body div:first-child {
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .welcome-modal .modal-footer {
        border-top-width: 0;
        padding: 20px 35px 20px 35px;
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617555/fire-jquery-script-on-first-page-load-and-then-never-again-for-that-user Use this..

Answer (score 0):

As Chinmayahd suggested. You need to control modal visibility. I had in past loaded dynamically templates with modals but showed the modals when I wanted. Divide 'loading' modal from showing modal.